# setting relationship to nil results in immediate persistance

Tags: activerecord

Why is A/R designed to persist changes to *relationships* as soon as they change, rather than waiting for a save operation? (rails 3.1.4)

...

Consider the following models for Book and Author:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

and the following seed data:

```
a = Author.new(:name => "Joe Author")
Book.create(:title => "The Book Title", :author => a)
```

...

Upon fetching a book, one can adjust the title and nothing is persisted until Book.save is called.

However, when you try to adjust the relationship to Author (e.g. setting it to nil), activerecord immediately persists the change.

This appears to be designed in, and is repeated by other A/R like implementations like mongoid. Why is A/R designed to persist changes to relationships as soon as they change, rather than waiting for a save operation?

Answer (score 0):

So if you check out the [ActiveRecord::Associations documentation section "Unsaved objects and associations"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Unsaved+objects+and+associations) under the `One-to-one associations" it states:

> - Assigning an object to a has_one association automatically saves that object and the object being replaced (if there is one), in order to update their foreign keys - except if the parent object is unsaved (new_record? == true).

and less relevantly

> - Assigning an object to a belongs_to association does not save the object, since the foreign key field belongs on the parent. It does not save the parent either.

So in this situation you're actually changing the `Author` record not the `Book` record. So even if you called `@book.save` it wouldn't change the relationship status (since `Author` holds the foreign key).

If you were to wait until the `@book.save` to save the `@book.author` then the `@book` object would have to **hold the state** of both the `old author` to remove the `book_id`, and the `new author` to set the `book_id`.